# Float:left being thrown off by varying size divs

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of `.section` divs that have one image and one title. They are all float:lefted. Everything is fine as long as the .section divs are all the same size. If one is bigger than the rest, is basically "holds up" the "row" underneath it.

Here is an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/qj4dzgyo/4/

As you can see, the section on the second row isn't floating entirely to the left because the one section in the top row has a longer title that makes the div bigger. Is there anyway I can get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If one is bigger than the rest, is basically "holds up" the "row" underneath it.

That’s how float works.

If you don’t want that, then use `display:inline-block` instead of float, see http://jsfiddle.net/qj4dzgyo/5/

(Notice that I changed the width of the elements from 20% to 19% in this example, so that still five of them fit on one line. You might want to read https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ as well in that regard.)

---

Alternatively, if you will always have five floated elements next to each other (seems to be a given, with a width of 20%), you could also just clear the float on every 5n+1-th one:

```
.section:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qj4dzgyo/6/

Answer (score 0):

just add `margin: 1px` to you `.section` class.

If you text is too big you may have to use flex box, but for your not that long texts like your example, this fix could do.

try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qj4dzgyo/7/)